# Rails 5 Capybara not founding already clicked button

Tags: capybara, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following test:

```
  it 'shows the current quantity of items inside cart' do
    item = create(:item)
    visit root_path
    click_link("add-item-#{item.id}")
    wait_for_ajax
    page.find('#notice-modal-ok').click
    click_link("add-item-#{item.id}")
    wait_for_ajax
    page.find('#notice-modal-ok').click
    expect(page).to have_selector('#cart-item-count', text: '2')
  end
```

It's basically a button with ajax thats show a success modal when return status 200. But, when the second ajax happens, for reason that I can't understand, the modal doesn't shows up. I can do this normally in dev environment.
Thanks for help!

---

Edit #1

I added a `save_and_open_screenshot` to try to debug this. The code in the end looked this way:

```
  it 'shows the current quantity of items inside cart' do
    item = create(:item)
    visit root_path
    click_link("add-item-#{item.id}")
    page.find('#notice-modal-ok', wait: 10).click
    expect(page).not_to have_selector('#notice-modal-ok')
    click_link("add-item-#{item.id}")
    save_and_open_screenshot # image
    page.find('#notice-modal-ok', wait: 10).click # this fails
    expect(page).to have_selector('#cart-item-count', text: '2', wait: 10)
  end
```

[image: Imgur]
Imagem number 1

As the images shows, the modal isn't appering on the second call. Here is the javascript thats shows it:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("a:regex(id,add-item-[0-9]+)").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var link = $(this).attr("href");

      $.ajax({
        url: link,
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          $('#notice-modal').modal('show');
          if(data.quantity) {
            $("#cart-item-count").css('display', 'block');
            $("#cart-item-count").html(data.quantity);
          } else {
            $("#cart-item-count").hide()
          }
        }
      });
    })
  });
```

And in development mode, it works normally. Hope this new infos help!

Comment: What driver are you using? Also, which line is the test failing on, and what is the exact error being raised?

Comment: I'm using `:selenium_chrome`. The second `page.find('#notice-modal-ok').click` is falling and this error is raised: `Capybara::ElementNotFound:
Unable to find css "#notice-modal-ok"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if the element with id of 'notice-modal-ok' is only appearing after the ajax request has completed then `wait_for_ajax` isn't required. Beyond that, assuming that clicking the modal doesn't affect the behavior of the add item link there are a few possibilities.  One is that the modal hasn't actually disappeared before the link click happens and that suppresses link behavior.  Another would be that `Capybara.default_max_wait_time' isn't set high enough for the hardware you're running on.  To test for these you can wait for the modal to be gone before clicking the link for the second time and also temporarily increase the max wait time

**Update:**  the root cause of the issue is that `semantic-ui` thinks the modal is still active (even though it has been closed) if you click the 'ok' button to close it before it has fully animated into place.  The way around this in the tests is to make sure the modal has class 'active' before clicking the `ok` button. An alternate solution would be to disable all animations in `semantic-ui` when testing (if it has that option) which would also speed up tests.

```
it 'shows the current quantity of items inside cart' do
  item = create(:item)
  visit root_path
  click_link("add-item-#{item.id}")
  page.find('#notice-modal.active #notice-modal-ok').click
  expect(page).not_to have_selector('#notice-modal') #verify/wait for the modal to disappear
  click_link("add-item-#{item.id}")
  page.find('#notice-modal.active #notice-modal-ok').click
  expect(page).to have_selector('#cart-item-count', text: '2')
end
```

Comment: I tried this solution but didn't work. I still getting the same error. I tried to use `save_and_open_page` after clicking in the link for the second time to check if the modal is there, and wasn't. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @RodrigoChaves Then something else is happening on the page after clicking the first modal that you're not telling us, other requests, page refreshes,etc. Where do you put the `byebug` that then allows the second modal to show up? Also, `save_and_open_page` is the wrong method to use to check the current state of pages since it doesn't always correctly reflect current state - you want to use `save_and_open_screenshot` to see the current state.

Comment: I added more info using `save_and_open_screenshot `. I hope this helps. And thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: @RodrigoChaves put `sleep 5` before the `save_and_open_screenshot` and see if it's visible then.  If not, it probably means the link click is being ignored for some reason.  You stated that if you added byebug it works, where do you add the byebug that makes it work?  Also what JS does clicking '#notice-modal-ok' trigger.  Another possibility is that your ajax call is failing - check 'log/test.log' for that, possibly a bad authenticity token error?

Comment: I added the `sleep 5` but the modal didn't apperead. I tried to use byebug again but it didn't apperead either. The JS for `#notice-modal-ok` is from the framework, [semantic-ui](http://semantic-ui.com/). I found `Could not log "render_template.action_view" event.` in log. This says anything to you?

Comment: @RodrigoChaves You can fix that error by rolling back to the previous version of rspec / rspec-rails -- they're working on fixing it.  If it's not working when you use byebug and step through, are you 100% sure this behavior actually works, and it's not raising JS errors or something?

Comment: I tried to downgrade to `'rspec-rails','3,5'`, but the same error occurred. In development, there is no error in JS. There is an another way to check for error?

Comment: @RodrigoChaves I'm afraid I don't have any more ideas, the info you've provided about what's happening/not happening is conflicting so I really have no clue what is going on anymore.

Comment: I'm sorry by been conflicting. Can you tell which points of the questions are been conflicting so I can improve the question? And thanks you so much for trying to help me! :D

Comment: @RodrigoChaves The log error - https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1800 - which definitely should have been fixed by rolling back rspec, the byebug working but then not working (which if it never worked completely changes the problem), etc.

Comment: Ah, I understand now! I downgraded and still apering nothing thats looks like an error in `test.log`. The byebug I posted because that was making it working but I wasn't able to reproduce it again. I'm sorry by confunsing it! I'm already removed this part of the question.

Comment: @RodrigoChaves If you create a standalone example that replicates the issue, or provide access to the actual code I can try and figure it out -- other than that I'm out of guesses.

Comment: The code is in an public repo in github. You can access it [here](https://github.com/rodriggochaves/dinnerdash2/tree/q01). The branch `q01` is where I'm made an changes that I said in comments.

Comment: @RodrigoChaves The issue is caused by what I think is a bug in semantic-ui.  If you close the modal before it has fully animated its appearance it thinks it's still active, and then won't show it again.  Answer updated -- still no need for 'wait_for_ajax'